# Display() function on Pycharm

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, display

I'm doing a code in python on Pycharm. But i want to use display() function that is only avaliable in Jupyter notebook. How can i use that same function "display()" in Pycharm?

Thanks a lot.

I tried install Iphyton on my Pycharm, but it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to give some more context about the circumstances wherein this specific problem occurs? Like machine, libraries, versions, e.g.

This helps in outlining what exactly is causing problems in your setup and
if so, something has to do with IPython.

Thanks for this topic!

Answer (score 0):

You can use display within pycharm. In jupyter or in the console.

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
df = pd.DataFrame(x)

display(df)
```

In pycharm jupyter you can omit 'display', since calling a DF by name seems to do the same as display(df)

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
df = pd.DataFrame(x)

df
```

Strangely, only in the last case pycharm jupyter offers the *Export Data to File* function

[image: Pycharm Export Data to File]